# Using switch cases in python lambda

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe containing data of a set of people, in which 'age' is one of the columns. Now I want to create another column in dataframe, which would tell if that person is a child or a middle aged person or senior citizen.

I know this can be implemented using the `pd.cut()` function. But I wanted to know if there is a way I can do it using a switch statement in lambda function inside `df.apply()`. It should be something like this:

```
if i between 0 and 10: Child
else if i between 10 and 30: Adult
else if i between 30 and 45: Middle aged
else if i between 45 and 60: Old
else if i > 60: Senior citizen
```

**EDIT**: the duplicate does not answer my question because I would like a solution that does not use `pd.cut()`.

Comment: Sorry, added new dupe solution, try `np.select`

Comment: Can we use switch cases in lambda expressions ?

Comment: There is more possible solutions, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column). `np.select` should be one of more performant